# How to exit the container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic as builder

ARG DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -L https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.41.0/doctl-1.41.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz  | tar xz
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/v1.4.3/argocd-linux-amd64 -o argocd

RUN chmod +x ./argocd
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl

RUN mv ./argocd /usr/local/bin/
RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/
RUN mv ./doctl /usr/local/bin/


CMD doctl auth init -t ${DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN} \
    doctl account get \
    if [ $? -eq 1 ] then exit fi
```

What am I trying to achieve, when `doctl account get` return code `1`, then it should not start running container.

The Dockerfile above does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've removed the `if [ $? -eq 1 ] then exit fi` and it worked.

The container will exit when then `doctl account get` exits.

Comment: Unrelatedly, note that passing in the access token via a build arg isn't very secure: the image will have the token embedded, so anyone who gets access to the image can extract. Since you only need it at runtime, better to pass it in at runtime via an environment variable or whatever other secrets mechanism your runtime platform provides.

Comment: I've created the container with `docker build -t argo-cli .` and run it `docker run -it --env=DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN=5e60c09030d1b6 argo-cli bash`.

Comment: Your `CMD` is a single command, `doctl auth ...` with 15 parameters after it (a couple of which are reserved shell words).  Do you mean to separate these with `&&` or `;`, or better still, write this into a shell script?

Comment: @ipinak Thanks so much. I should not with as argument bash.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you mean starting the container in the background [not interacting with it], so,
You can run it in detached mode using the option -d

```
docker run -it -d image_name /bin/bash
```

then you can use

```
docker exec container_id /bin/bash
```

to work again to the same container

see a more detailed review [exiting Docker container](https://vsupalov.com/exit-docker-container/https://)

you can search the Docker's doc too.

Comment: The `docker run` construct will run an interactive shell, as a background process, instead of the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  This doesn't seem like it's especially useful, and it's not clear how this solves the problem in the question.